# list all files with extension .log except one

Tags: bash, ls

I would like to list all files with extension `.log` except the file `backup.log`.

I have tried using this command:

```
ls *.log -I "backup.log"
```

But all the log files are listed, even `backup.log`!

How could I list all the log files except `backup.log`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The shell expands the wildcard, so `ls` gets `backup.log` as one of the parameters.

Use an extended pattern (enabled by `shopt -s extglob`):

```
ls !(backup).log
```

Comment: I did not think of this shell trick yet, simple and useful!

Comment: I just tried this and I didn't work. It lists all files except backup.log. What I want is to list all log files except backup.log.

Comment: @JavierCintrón: Did you use `!(backup).log` or `!(backup.log)`?

Comment: Geez man :) I used  ls !(backup.log). I confirm that ls !(backup).log is the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 6):

One possibility would be:

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name \*.log -a -not -name backup.log
```

i.e. find all files in the current directory or below, with an exact depth of 1 (so really only in the current directory and not the name of the current directory itself) with name matching the pattern `*.log` and not `backup.log`

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: But kind of complicated

Comment: @JavierCintrón: yes, but once you want to do anything with the files, it's easier to `find -exec` than to worry about parsing the output of `ls`, which you cannot usually do in a safe manner.

Comment: You have the reason man. In my case I just needed to count the amount of log files except backup.log, which I did using this command: ls -laht !(backup).log | wc -l. If I had needed to do anything with these files inside a loop, I would have used your solution.

Comment: Well, the point where things get ugly is when you have spaces or newlines in file names, which throws off `wc -l`.

Comment: Geez man I am going to ask that too in another question of course.

Answer (score 1):

[TXR](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/):

```
$ ls *.patch
install-tests.patch  match.patch  netbsd.patch  specials.patch  wlist.patch
$ txr -t '(glob "*.patch")'
install-tests.patch
match.patch
netbsd.patch
specials.patch
wlist.patch
$ txr -t '(set-diff (glob "*.patch") (glob "[mn]*.patch"))'
install-tests.patch
specials.patch
wlist.patch
```

Answer (score 1):

you can skip Backup keyword from  shell expansion by using !(keyword)

```
ubuntu@vm-ubuntu:~$ ls *.log

1.log  2.log  backup.log

ubuntu@vm-ubuntu:~$ ls  !(backup).log

1.log  2.log
```

Answer (score -2):

What about parsing the output of `ls` through `grep`:

```
ls -l *.log | grep -v backup.log
```

Comment: What if you have symlinks pointing to `backup.log`?  How about other files with names ending in `backup.log`?

Comment: ... or even ***containing*** `backup.log`?